Grid траблы с блоками
Здраствуйте, помогите с grid-ом
Делаю вёрстку по PP, столкнулся с тем что у меня образовывается 4 блока в грид сетке, вместо 3х (скрин 1 и 2), если применить gap что бы сделать отступы, то он посчитает все 4 отступа
Не могу понять, почему так получается, прошу помочь, код прилагаю ниже
если кому потребуется полностью весь код, могу скинуть в файлообменнике


/*style.css*/
.about {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.about__wrap {
  max-width: 70%;
}

.about-section {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.about__list {
  --gap: 32px;
  --screen: 2;
  --width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, calc(var(--width) - var(--gap) / var(--screen)));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 292px);
  gap: 32px;

} 

.about__item {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 295px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.about__item:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 622px;
  transform: scale(1);
  grid-row: 1/3;
  align-items: end;
  background-image: url("../img/section-banner-background.jpg");
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.about__inner {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 196px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0, 0.5);
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.about-descr {
  width: 56%;
  color: var(--color-white);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.item-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid var(--color-orange);
  padding: 18px 36px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out, border-color .3s ease-in-out;
}

.item-btn:focus, .item-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-orange);
}

.item-btn:active {
  background-color: var(--color-dark-orange);
  border-color: var(--color-dark-orange);
}

.item-btn__link {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 19.5px;
  color: var(--color-white);
}

.about__item:nth-child(2){
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gray);
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-image: url("../img/background-about-upper.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 190px 165px;
  background-position: top 64px left 60px;
}

.about__item:nth-child(3){
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gray);
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-image: url("../img/background-about-under.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 190px 165px;
  background-position: top 64px left 60px;
}

.item__wrap {
  max-width: 452px;
  margin-left: 21%;
}

.text__descr {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
/*style.css*/

/*media.css (max-width: 320px)*/
  .about__item:first-child {
    grid-row: span 2;
    min-height: 400px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: top;
  }

  .about__inner {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--color-black);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 13px;
  }

  .about-descr {
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
  }

  .about-section {
    margin-top: 14px;
  }

  .about__list {
    gap: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  }

  .about-descr {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .item-btn {
    padding: 9px 42px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-orange);
  }

  .item-btn__link {
    color: var(--color-orange);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14.63px;
  }

  .about__item:nth-child(2),
  .about__item:nth-child(3) {
    border: none;
    background-size: 64px 49px;
    background-position: top 80px left 0px;
  }

  .item__wrap {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 290px;
  }

  .subtitle {
    max-width: 290px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 21.94px;
  }

  .subtitle-descr {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 28px;
  }

  .caption-descr {
    word-spacing: -3px;
  }
/*media.css*/
    <section class="about offset flex">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="about__wrap">
          <h2 class="caption">О&nbsp;нас</h2>
          <p class="caption-descr">
            Также как перспективное планирование создаёт необходимость включения в&nbsp;производственный план целого ряда внеочередных мероприятий с&nbsp;учётом комплекса экспериментов, поражающих по&nbsp;своей масштабности и&nbsp;грандиозности. А&nbsp;также диаграммы связей могут быть описаны максимально подробно. Мы&nbsp;вынуждены отталкиваться от&nbsp;того, что убеждённость некоторых оппонентов требует от&nbsp;нас анализа как самодостаточных, так и&nbsp;внешне зависимых концептуальных решений! Следует отметить, что высококачественный прототип будущего проекта предопределяет высокую востребованность позиций, занимаемых участниками в&nbsp;отношении поставленных задач. Мы&nbsp;вынуждены отталкиваться от&nbsp;того, что высококачественный прототип будущего проекта способствует повышению качества экспериментов.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="about-section">
          <ul class="about__list r-list ">
            <li class="about__item">
              <div class="about__inner">
                <p class="caption-descr about-descr">
                  Принимая во&nbsp;внимание показатели успешности, перспективное планирование способствует подготовке и&nbsp;реализации новых принципов
                </p>
                <button class="item-btn"><a href="#" class="item-btn__link">Подробнее</a></button>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="about__item">
              <div class="item__wrap">
                <h3 class="subtitle">Консультация с&nbsp;широким активом</h3>
                <p class="subtitle-descr text__descr">А&nbsp;также свежий взгляд на&nbsp;привычные вещи&nbsp;&mdash; безусловно открывает новые горизонты для как самодостаточных, так и&nbsp;внешне зависимых концептуальных решений</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="about__item">
              <div class="item__wrap">
                <h3 class="subtitle">В&nbsp;своём стремлении повысить</h3>
                <p class="subtitle-descr text__descr">Качество жизни, они забывают, что сплочённость команды профессионалов представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки прогресса профессионального сообщества</p>  
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>






Почему бы просто не сделать grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr?
